# Display data attribute value with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using a WordPress plugin to display events on a calendar. It has the following markup to display days:

```
<th id="tribe-events-monday" title="Monday" data-day-abbr="Mon">Monday</th>
```

Instead of displaying "Monday", I'd like it to display "Mon". Is it possible to output the data attribute (data-day-abbr) using CSS?

This would be a prefered workaround, otherwise, I'll need to create child template files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by hiding the `th` content's visibility, and replacing it using CSS' `content` and `attr`:

```css
[data-day-abbr]:before {
  content: attr(data-day-abbr);
  visibility: visible;
}

th {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="tribe-events-monday" title="Monday" data-day-abbr="Mon">Monday</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I recommend this answer as a perfect one.

Comment: Great answer. Am I correct in thinking that screen readers will still have the ability to read the days of the week?

Answer (score 1):

Access data-day-abbr in CSS and set its value on a pseudo element (before):

```
#tribe-events-monday:before {
     content: attr(data-day-abbr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is "hide" the text in the `th` by setting it's font-size to zero.

Than add an `:after` element and fill it with the data attribute.
[More information](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-access-and-use-data-attributes-in-your-css/#getting-a-data-attribute-s-value-in-css)

```css
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 0;
}
th:after {
  content: attr(data-day-abbr);
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="tribe-events-monday" title="Monday" data-day-abbr="Mon">Monday</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use text-indent and ::before

```css
[data-day-abbr] {
  text-indent: -100vw;/* at least enough to hide text */
}
[data-day-abbr]::after {
  content: attr(data-day-abbr);
  float:left;/* or display: block;*/
  text-indent: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th title="Monday"    data-day-abbr="Mon">Monday</th>
    <th title="Tuesday"   data-day-abbr="Tue">Tuesday</th>
    <th title="wednesday" data-day-abbr="Wed">Wednesda</th>
    <th title="Thursday"  data-day-abbr="Thu">Thursday</th>
    <th title="friday"    data-day-abbr="Fri">friday</th>
    <th title="Saturday"  data-day-abbr="Sat">Saturday</th>
    <th title="Sunday"    data-day-abbr="Sun">Sunday</th>
  </tr>
</table>
  </tr>
</table>
```